# Can't Get a Javascript Runtime Installed/Recognized in RedHat (for Rails 3.1)

Tags: javascript, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, coffeescript

Trying to setup a production deployment on a dedicated box running RedHat (64bit):

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 (Tikanga)
```

For the life of me, I can't get a Javascript Runtime installed and/or recognized by my Rails 3.1.0rc6 app.

I've done a gem install of execjs, therubyracer, libv8, and mustang ... still get this error after restarting:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
  (in /var/www/demo-setup/releases/20110825184931/app/assets/javascripts/demos.js.coffee)):
```

Also installed node.js but still get this error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the solution is, but maybe this will help:

The error is being thrown from ExecJS [here](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/blob/master/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb). If `therubyracer` gem is installed, then it should be detected by the line `require "v8"` [here](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/blob/master/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb).

Can you `require "v8"` successfully from `irb`? If so, then that tells you that Rails is being run on a different set of gems somehow. Are you using rvm?